# Spark Job Container exited with exitCode: -1000

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been struggling to run sample job with spark 2.0.0 in yarn cluster mode, job exists with  exitCode: -1000 without any other clues. Same job runs properly in local mode.

**Spark command:**

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.yarn.stagingDir=/xyz/warehouse/spark" \
--queue xyz \
--class com.xyz.TestJob \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf "spark.local.dir=/xyz/warehouse/tmp" \
/xyzpath/java-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $@
```

**TestJob class:**

```
public class TestJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        System.out.println(
                "TOtal count:"+
                        jsc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4})).count());
        jsc.stop();
    }
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
17/10/04 22:26:52 INFO Client: Application report for application_1506717704791_130756 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/10/04 22:26:52 INFO Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: N/A
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: root.xyz
         start time: 1507181210893
         final status: UNDEFINED
         tracking URL: http://xyzserver:8088/proxy/application_1506717704791_130756/
         user: xyz
17/10/04 22:26:53 INFO Client: Application report for application_1506717704791_130756 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/10/04 22:26:54 INFO Client: Application report for application_1506717704791_130756 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/10/04 22:26:55 INFO Client: Application report for application_1506717704791_130756 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/10/04 22:26:56 INFO Client: Application report for application_1506717704791_130756 (state: FAILED)
17/10/04 22:26:56 INFO Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: Application application_1506717704791_130756 failed 5 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1506717704791_130756_000005 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://xyzserver:8088/cluster/app/application_1506717704791_130756Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: root.xyz
         start time: 1507181210893
         final status: FAILED
         tracking URL: http://xyzserver:8088/cluster/app/application_1506717704791_130756
         user: xyz
17/10/04 22:26:56 INFO Client: Deleted staging directory /xyz/spark/.sparkStaging/application_1506717704791_130756
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1506717704791_130756 finished with failed status
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1213)
```

**When I browse the page `http://xyzserver:8088/cluster/app/application_1506717704791_130756` it doesn't exists.**

**No Yarn application logs found-**

```
$yarn logs -applicationId application_1506717704791_130756 
/apps/yarn/logs/xyz/logs/application_1506717704791_130756 does not have any log files.
```

What could be the possibly rootcause of this error and how to get detailed error logs?

Comment: You application never starts running. Most likely due to some configuration error for Spark on YARN. Have you gone through this : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html ?

Comment: The issue was with one of the configuration params. When I removed it started working. BTW thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending nearly one whole day I found the rootcause. When I remove `spark.yarn.stagingDir` it starts working and I am still not sure why spark is complaining about it-

**Previous Spark Submit-**

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.yarn.stagingDir=/xyz/warehouse/spark" \
--queue xyz \
--class com.xyz.TestJob \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf "spark.local.dir=/xyz/warehouse/tmp" \
/xyzpath/java-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $@
```

**New-**

```
spark-submit \
--queue xyz \
--class com.xyz.TestJob \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf "spark.local.dir=/xyz/warehouse/tmp" \
/xyzpath/java-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $@
```

Comment: Quite late here, but I managed to solve this problem by specifying a fully qualified staging dir such as spark.yarn.stagingDir='hdfs://name-node/path/to/staging'.