# Why spark-submit fails with `spark.yarn.stagingDir` with master yarn and deploy-mode cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I came across a scenario when I supply  `spark.yarn.stagingDir` to spark-submit it starts failing and it doesn't give any clue about the rootcause, and I spent quite long time to figure out it's because of `spark.yarn.stagingDir` parameter. Why spark-submit fails when supply `spark.yarn.stagingDir` this parameter?

Check related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578669/spark-job-container-exited-with-exitcode-1000/46592039#46592039) for more details

**Command which fails:**

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.yarn.stagingDir=/xyz/warehouse/spark" \
--queue xyz \
--class com.xyz.TestJob \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf "spark.local.dir=/xyz/warehouse/tmp" \
/xyzpath/java-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**When I remove `spark.yarn.stagingDir`, it starts working:**

```
spark-submit \
    --queue xyz \
    --class com.xyz.TestJob \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf "spark.local.dir=/xyz/warehouse/tmp" \
    /xyzpath/java-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**Exception stacktrace:**

> Application application_1506717704791_145448 finished with failed
>   status
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1167)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1213)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered exactly the same problem when I set `spark.yarn.stagingDir` as `/tmp` (while it worked fine once I removed this very configuration entry).

My solution is to specify the full HDFS path like `hdfs://hdfs_server_name/tmp` instead of merely `/tmp`. Hope it works for you.